# Why does this give `error converting data type varchar to numeric`

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am having a SQL issue, and I have boiled it down to this:

```
if isnull(5.5,'') = isnull(null,'') select 0 else select 1
```

which throws the error `Error Converting data type varchar to numeric.`

Why is this throwing this error, and how to resolve?

Comment: The Docs states: `replacement_value: Is the expression to be returned if check_expression is NULL. replacement_value must be of a type that is implicitly convertible to the type of check_expresssion.` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Read what you wrote. `if isnull(5.5, '')` returns 5.5 (as 5.5 is not null). `isnull(null, '')` returns `''`, because null is null. 5.5 is numeric, `''` is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simpler expression (which is equivalent to your expression) gives the same error:

```
if 5.5 = '' select 0 else select 1
```

You're comparing a varchar to a numeric type as the error indicates.

You can `CAST` your expression to match types:

```
if CAST(isnull(5.5,'') AS VARCHAR)  = isnull(null,'') select 0 else select 1
```

Comment: I don't get it.  There is an implicit conversion from numeric to varchar, so I don't see why an error is thrown.

Comment: @GregGum Interestingly, there seems to be an implicit conversion from varchar to numeric, if possible, but not the other way, so e.g. `if 5.5 = '0' select 0 else select 1` *doesn't* throw an error.